# refresh directory before opening a textfile from SDCard

Tags: android, file, directory, android-sdcard

I'm opening a textfile from the sdcard, its my logfile.

Now the problem is, that the directory does not refresh itself. I have to refresh it by hand in the file explorer, to open the file with correct content.

But I don't want to open it via the file explorer, but on a Button Click. It works well and the file opens, but the content is not correct.

Is there something to refresh a directory before reading from it?